# LaTeX Error: File `conference.cls' not found

Tags: ieeetran

i want to write a paper in IEEEtran but i am encountering an error named above as title suggest  LaTeX Error: File `conference.cls' not found.
i don't know how to get rid of this error
kindly help me as soon as possible

Answer (score 3):

I think you want

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
```

rather than

```
\documentclass{conference}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also the possibility of

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt,conference]{ieeeconf}
```

Which ---although it is not the official IEEE class for conferences (The one Ian Thompson is pointing you out is)--- it is often used for IEEE conferences.